Is there a way to classify chemicals as GHG positive/negative based to whether they have a higher tendency to react with a GHG or be a side product?
I have a list of chemicals that I want to classify as Greenhouse Gas (GHG) positive, neutral or negative based on whats the probability it would be
To give an example: lets take the case of diethanolamine. Theoretically in papers, it seems that diethanolamine is highly used for CO2 capture, so it will be GHG negative. That is increasing it would reduce CO2. Similarly, Nitrate compounds can undergo denitrification and release Nitrous oxide, thus they can be classified as GHG Positive. But it seems that Pb (lead) compounds do not do either, so they can be classified as GHG neutral.
Is there a good way to do this? I was thinking around some numerical way like Entropy/Gibbs free energy, etc. The system doesn't have to be fool proof but something that would classify 70-80% of them correctly with a fair theoretical foundation would be great. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

This is very difficult. To start you need to redefine categories. There are volatile chemicals that act directly as GHG in the atmosphere, or are precursors to (possibly multiple) GHG (and therefore might be regarded as equivalent to a certain amount of CO2). Others may catalyze conversion to GHGs (as in a catalytic converter). And manufacturing chemicals directly or indirectly contributes to formation of GHGs. Consider ammonia. Its manufacture requires much potentially non-renewable energy. Converted into fertilizer it can also result in GHG formation.

What does "side product" in the title refer to? What is the main product, what process?

@BuckThorn - Yeah its a difficult question, no doubt, its a little unconventional.
Perhaps another way to look at it could be can I find neutral chemicals from my list of chemicals, such that, these chemicals are generally not produced in any process that also produces CO2 for example, or are also not highly reactive with CO2.
I thought maybe difference in Gibbs energy/enthalpy change may help with saying whether these are reactive with CO2. List of chemicals is in the right corner of this website Link

@PaulKolk The process is unknown unfortunately. Its mainly about how understanding how reactive a chemical would be with CO2 or how reactive it will be with something that generates CO2.

@metrics24 I recommend asking something about $\ce{CO2}$ separately if this is the most interesting GHG to you. There are too many unknowns to fully answer the question as it is presently written.

Thanks @PaulKolk I'll re-ask the question as a new one. Would be great if someone can come up with some answer, some measurement errors are okay with it.

If I understand your question correctly, you have a given list of compounds, and you want to know if they can be considered "good" or "bad" in the sense that they either contribute to $\ce{CO2}$ emissions or "neutralize" $\ce{CO2}$ emissions. It is an interesting question but very hard to answer in general terms, as you have not given a lot of detail to go on. (I apologize to the moderators if I am abusing the policy by writing this as an "answer" anyway and not a comment)
But here is an attempt at an answer (actually two answers):
Answer #1: You cannot, as a general rule, use reaction enthalpy or Gibbs energy for a reaction between your compound and $\ce{CO2}$ as a guiding principle.
First, as someone wrote in a different version of your question, because the reaction may be thermodynamically favorable but kinetically unavailable, making the reaction too unlikely to be useful.
Secondly, if you are looking for chemicals that can be used to trap $\ce{CO2}$ in a scalable process, it is useful to consider also reactions that are thermodynamically unfavorable reactions that can still provide an efficient $\ce{CO2}$ sink if you have an external energy source. For instance, you might consider some chemical process that can use solar heat to trap $\ce{CO2}$ without further releasing any GHG.
Answer #2: If, however, you are looking at your list of chemicals from a life cycle perspective and want to have a way of determining the GWP of any chemical, the problem becomes increasingly complex.
As a general rule, the GWP of a chemical is usually determined by its radiative forcing which is another way of describing how much the compound absorbs infrared light, thereby contributing to warming the atmosphere (if it is emitted). Now, I read your question to mean a slightly different way of measuring GWP based on the reaction with $\ce{CO2}$. It seems like a bold and creative move, but it needs further refinement.
Any LCA expert would tell you that you need to apply strict definitions to all parameters. Your GWP values can only be determined if there to any mass flow can be determined how it contributes to that parameter according to its definition. In your question, you are very vague on exactly what it is that you want to measure. You say that you maybe want to have something that reacts with $\ce{CO2}$, or maybe how much $\ce{CO2}$ is emitted in its production process. To solve the problem, you need to zero in on your definition.
With that said, I think that the second scenario, that is, the emissions from manufacturing of the compound, may be the easier way to go. You need to do some digging to find out a unit process for each of the chemicals in the list. Once you have done the groundwork, you can use that as your database. I say that it is easier, because even though it is possible to identify chemical reactions that will "neutralize" $\ce{CO2}$, you then also need to take the risk that the new compound formed in this way, will decompose, releasing the $\ce{CO2}$ again.
Let me know if this was helpful. (And to the moderators: I will not be sad if my answer is removed. I understand!)

Thank you so much for taking the time with this.
I am not looking at the GWP of the chemical itself, so Answer #2 may not be exaclty what I need.
But your answer #1 is quite relevant. So it seems that the drawback of using change in Gibbs energy is that:

A reaction that is thermodynamically feasible may not be kinetically feasible.
A reaction that is thermodynamically not feasible may still be carried out in the industrial setting by providing external energy.

Is that all the drawbacks you can think of? Like I said, I am comfortable with some errors.

Additionally, I am most interested to find the chemicals in the list that will never be on the right side of an equation where CO2 is on the left. And chemicals that will never be on left side of an equation where CO2 is on the right. Which I consider to be neutral chemicals.

If I do it systematically:

Put the chemical on the left and CO2 on the right of a chemical equation to compute the change in entropy. A positive change will tell me that it is thermodynamically feasible without any external energy (kinetically it may or maynot), a negative one will tell me that it is thermodynamically not feasible without external energy.

As long as the negative one is very high, I can be very (or atleast more) sure that this reaction will not take place? And I can classify it as neutral. What would be a good threshold for a very high change?

Similarly: 2. Put CO2 on the left and the chemical on the right of a chemical equation to compute the change in entropy. A positive change will tell me that it is thermodynamically feasible without any external energy (kinetically it may or maynot), a negative one will tell me that it is thermodynamically not feasible without external energy. As long as the negative one is very high, I can be very (or atleast more) sure that this reaction will not take place? And I can classify it as neutral. Again what would be a good threshold for a very high change?

I do see the point that the change in entropy for 2 is just going to be the same value but a different sign compared to 1st. But as long as these reactions never happen either way, that works for me.
The concern I would have with it is, that these are not the only two chemicals that will be present in the equation. There will perhaps be more reactants and more products, which also contribute to Change in entropy. How do I manage for that?

I am glad to see that you have some ideas already. I think you need to do the work yourself for all the chemicals on your list. There is no easy way to give a general answer. That said, if CO2 is to the right in the chemical reaction equation, that usually indicates a spontaneous reaction, at least for organic compounds. If X (your compound) and O2 gives CO2 and H2O it means you have a combustion reaction. This is spontaneous but may need some help to get going.
